# Need a Json Schema which allows having logic conditionals on object items of an array

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

I have the following Json property of type array with items of type object; it corresponds to a scenario when you have one or multiple drivers where there exists one and only one primary driver and zero or any number of non-primary drivers :

```
{
        "driver": [
          {
            "driverId": 12839,
            "isPrimary": true
          },
          {
            "driverId": 23843,
            "isPrimary": false
          }
        ],
}
```

`"driver"` property is valid only if all following requirements are met:

1. `driverId` for each item should be unique.
2. only one item is allowed to have `"isPrimary": true`
3. there must be one and only one item with `"isPrimary": true`; there can be zero or any number of items with `"isPrimary": false`

Now I am looking for Json Schema that Implements the mentioned requirements; the following are the examples of the `"driver"` that would be valid:

```
1.
    {                                                   
            "driver": [       
              {
                "driverId": 12839,
                "isPrimary": true
              }
            ]
    }
2.
    {                                                   
            "driver": [       
              {
                "driverId": 12812,
                "isPrimary": true
              },
          {
                "driverId": 38849,
                "isPrimary": false
              },
          {
                "driverId": 34323,
                "isPrimary": false
              }
            ]
    }
```

and the following examples would fail the validation:

```
  1.
        {                                                   
                "driver": [       
                  {
                    "driverId": 12839,
                    "isPrimary": false
                  }
                ]
        }
    2.
        {                                                   
                "driver": [       
                  {
                    "driverId": 12839,
                    "isPrimary": false
                  },       
                  {
                    "driverId": 34564,
                    "isPrimary": false
                  }
                ]
        }
    3.
        {                                                   
                "driver": [       

                ]
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON schema doesn't support such requirements.

Depending on the validator, you can implement this requirement as a custom keyword  (e.g. in JavaScript with [Ajv](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv) - I am the author).

Comment: @esp.the Json validation is going to be part of my Middle Layer logic; there is a source system which is sending json files to my application, I'd like to have some sort of a config. file driven rules engine(in this case Json Schema) which allows me to validate these json files, if they are valid I deserialize them and push them to database. if not I throw them away I am using .NET platform and C# language and my goal was to use Json.NET for validation. with that being said do you still think Ajv is a suitable option for me ?